# How to get a dua accepted?

Tags: salat, allah, dua, tawba, blessings-of-allah

How to get my dua answered? How to earn Allah's mercy? I have been praying desperately for past many months but life still is not improving significantly. Sometimes things improve and then they become even worse.  Does that mean Allah is angry at me?  I am in so much need of receiving Allah's mercy to overcome my hardships.  In what ways can I receive it.

Answer (score 1):

Being a sincere believer aside, never ever forget that Allah might be doing you the greatest favor by not accepting your dua, or that He may be erasing your sins by not accepting your dua. Thus, a sincere believer's dua is always accepted one way or another. We just do not know how.